# How to change the datapoint y value of a chart in ASP.Net with a jQuery slider?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I want to make a dynamic graph with a sliderbar as input. I tried it with an ASP.Net chart and a jQuery slider widget. However I have no idea how to change the 
y value of the chart with the `ui.value` of the slider.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#slider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 50,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#slide").html("slide= " + ui.value)                      
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="329px" Width="448px">
  <Titles><asp:Title Text="sliderwaarde" /></Titles>
  <Series>                    
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Bar">
      <Points>
        <asp:DataPoint  AxisLabel="slider1" YValues="......." />
      </Points>
    </asp:Series>
  </Series>
  <ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
      <AxisX Title="Sliders"></AxisX>
      <AxisY Title="Waarde"></AxisY>
    </asp:ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

I want a dynamic chart that interacts with the value of de slider